# Json flattening in PySpark with multiple array fields

Tags: json, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a problem statement where i need to Flatten Json data containing arrays (list of dictionaries). While flattening one of the array fields (version)will become column's parameter. I have a dataframe created from Json which looks like this:

```
-id (string)
-as_of_date (string)
-past_features (array) (version values can take values 3months/6months/9months )
  -height (string)
  -width (string)
  -screensize (string)
  -smartdevice (boolean)
  -version(string)
-future_features (array)(version values can take values 3months/6months/9months)
  -height (string)
  -width (string)
  -screensize (string)
  -smartdevice (boolean)
  -version(string)
```

How to flatten this to below schema such that i create 1 record per json record only but creating several columns like below.
Note the version field is not a column ib below schema , but instead embedded in column names and each versions data is flattened together in a single row.Final flattened schema looks like below:

```
-id (string)
-as_of_date (string)
-past_features_3m_height (string)
-past_features_3m_width (string)
-past_features_3m_screensize (string)
-past_features_3m_smartdevice (boolean)
-past_features_6m_height (string)
-past_features_6m_width (string)
-past_features_6m_screensize (string)
-past_features_6m_smartdevice (boolean)
-past_features_9m_height (string)
-past_features_9m_width (string)
-past_features_9m_screensize (string)
-past_features_9m_smartdevice (boolean)
-future_features_3m_height (string)
-future_features_3m_width (string)
-future_features_3m_screensize (string)
-future_features_3m_smartdevice (boolean)
-future_features_6m_height (string)
-future_features_6m_width (string)
-future_features_6m_screensize (string)
-future_features_6m_smartdevice (boolean)
-future_features_9m_height (string)
-future_features_9m_width (string)
-future_features_9m_screensize (string)
-future_features_9m_smartdevice (boolean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten it using [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) and [pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html).

This is a simplified jsonl example created with json schema faker just to try the solution:

```
{ "id": "a", "as_of_date": "yes", "past_features": [ { "width": -66105819, "version": "6m", "height": -70464769 }, { "width": 12820987, "version": "6m", "height": 18639815 }, { "width": -23098401, "version": "9m", "height": 77217612 } ] }
{ "id": "c", "as_of_date": "no", "past_features": [ { "width": -4552888, "version": "3m", "height": 98265428 } ] }
{ "id": "b", "as_of_date": "yes", "past_features": [ { "width": 35952886, "version": "3m", "height": -85501281 }, { "width": 35068589, "version": "6m" }, { "width": 97965007, "version": "9m", "height": -59246801 } ] }
```

First, read the data:

```py
>>> df = spark.read.json('data.jsonl')
```

This is the schema we have (I've removed `future_features` just to keep the example simple and clean):

```py
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- as_of_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- past_features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- height: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- width: long (nullable = true)
```

Explode to get one row per item on `past_features` array:

```py
>>> df_exploded = df.withColumn('past_features',  F.explode('past_features'))
>>> df_exploded.show()
+----------+---+--------------------+
|as_of_date| id|       past_features|
+----------+---+--------------------+
|       yes|  a|{-70464769, 6m, -...|
|       yes|  a|{18639815, 6m, 12...|
|       yes|  a|{77217612, 9m, -2...|
|        no|  c|{98265428, 3m, -4...|
|       yes|  b|{-85501281, 3m, 3...|
|       yes|  b|{null, 6m, 35068589}|
|       yes|  b|{-59246801, 9m, 9...|
+----------+---+--------------------+
```

Once we have one row per feature, we group by `id` and `pivot` over `version` to produce one different column per `version` value (i.e, three columns, one for "3m", other for "6m" and other for "9m"):

```py
>>> fields = ['height', 'width']
>>> versions = ['3m', '6m', '9m']
>>> # group by at_of_date to keep it after grouping (probably there is a more efficient and elegant solution)
>>> df_pivoted = df_exploded.groupBy('id', 'as_of_date')\
        .pivot('past_features.version', versions)\
        .agg(F.first('past_features'))
>>> df_pivoted.show()
+---+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|as_of_date|                  3m|                  6m|                  9m|
+---+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  a|       yes|                null|{-70464769, 6m, -...|{77217612, 9m, -2...|
|  b|       yes|{-85501281, 3m, 3...|{null, 6m, 35068589}|{-59246801, 9m, 9...|
|  c|        no|{98265428, 3m, -4...|                null|                null|
+---+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Lastly use `select` to get the feature fields:

```py
>>> df_flattened = df_pivoted.select('id', 'as_of_date',
        *[F.col(v + '.' + f).alias(v + '_' + f) for v in versions for f in fields])
>>> df_flattened.show()
+---+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id|as_of_date|3m_height|3m_width|6m_height| 6m_width|9m_height| 9m_width|
+---+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  a|       yes|     null|    null|-70464769|-66105819| 77217612|-23098401|
|  b|       yes|-85501281|35952886|     null| 35068589|-59246801| 97965007|
|  c|        no| 98265428|-4552888|     null|     null|     null|     null|
+---+----------+---------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

And that's it! Adding the fields that I have ignored for the sake of simplicity should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. This really helps me in flattening the data as desired. One last query on this , if there are other non-array simple string fields apart from id and as_of_date used in group by , how can i include them in the dataframe as well , because they will be dropped if i use groupby and pivot.

Comment: I guess the only solution is to create another dataframe selecting the desired fields, and after grouping and pivoting, join it by id to add those fields.

Comment: Exactly what i thought so and implemented , thanks again for your time and inputs.